# Application is blurry on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, graphics, windows-8.1, compatibility, blurry

I code 2d graphics c++ application, when resolution is not native and fullscreen, graphics looks **blurry**. This problem appears only on Win 8.1. When I use *compatibility mode* with Win 8 or lower, it's looks good.

I've tried to Disable Display Scaling On High DPI in Compatibility settings, but it has no effect. DPI awareness is set to YES in manifest also. Application uses rather old engine (HGE 181).

What can I do? I don't want to set compatibility every time when using Win 8.1.

What is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem once where I made an application in C++ and everything was blurry as well, some causes are bad resolution, old engines, engines aren't compatible with the OS.